# What is the darkest color human bowel movement can become?

Tags: human-biology

I assume a healthy human, with usual nutrition, without using any drugs or supplements.

Comment: I find this question difficult for several reasons. You assume "normal" nutrition - what is normal? A meal with spinach gives different colour than beetroot stew. I assume, this is about healthy human (since blood in stool can result in dark colour).  And how would a proper answer look like - providing a colour hex code, or similar?

Comment: Yeah, it's difficult.
For me, ideally, a good answer should contain a colour hex code and the type(s) of nutrition responsible for the dark colour.

Comment: Unless you define what normal is, your question would be considered opinion based and hence put on hold.

Comment: By normal, I mean that things like drugs and medication should be excluded. 
I know that it's not always easy to differentiate between drug, medication and 'normal' nutrition, but there, I'll have to just trust for further specification in the answers.

Comment: You can say in a healthy human, with usual nutrition, without using any drugs or supplements...and put this in your question.

Comment: @MichaelBauer then can you please [edit] your question to add all the necessary details.

Comment: btw, why is this still on hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The darkest stool in a healthy human is **black.** It can result from eating **black licorice, blueberries, blood sausages, Oreo cookies** or **grape juice.**

Other foods that may cause almost black stools: dark chocolate, beets, cranberries, prunes, dark green leafy vegetables, such as spinach or kale.

They are not nutrients, but natural or artificial dyes in the food, that can turn stool black.

Black, tarry and smelly stool is suspicious for bleeding from the upper gastrointestinal stomach (from mouth to stomach), since the acid in the stomach turns blood black.

Sources: ([Medline Plus](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/003130.htm), [OU Medicine](https://www.oumedicine.com/Public/Symptom/SymptomPeds/stoolscolor.htm), [25Doctors.com](https://www.25doctors.com/black-stool))